# how to use FOSBUNDLE login SESSION

Tags: php, symfony, session, fosuserbundle

I using FOSBUNDLE with symfony 2.8 I maked the login / sign up and that worked and connected to database successfully but I have a proplem with passing session variable to other pages

I tried this simple code to output the session on a web page but I get this error

Failed to start the session: already started by PHP.
and when I remove

```
$session = new Session();
$session->start();
```

I get this error

Notice: Undefined variable: session

```
<?php

namespace site\blogBundle\Controller;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {

        $session = new Session();
        $session->start();
        $session->set('username', 'Drak');
        $session->get('username');
        return $this->render('siteblogBundle:Default:index.html.twig' ['test' => $session]);
    }
}
```

so where the problem ?

Comment: If your user is authenticated, you can just retrieve it like this : $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

Comment: @MathieuDormeval thank you that's worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your user is authenticated, you can just retrieve it, like this :

```
$user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUs‌​er();
```

For more informations about security, check [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html) ans.

Answer (score 1):

```
(1) $session = new Session();
(2) $session->start();
(3) $session->set('username', 'Drak');
(4) $session->get('username');
(5) return $this->render('siteblogBundle:Default:index.html.twig' ['test' => $session]);
```

(1) If you want to work with a session you have to keep this line

(2) This is what's causing the warning. Depending on your setup Symfony will likely already start a session. You can guard against this warning by doing the following:

```
if (!$session->isStarted()) {
    $session->start();
}
```

(3) This will set a username in the session. Please be aware that this your username and not related in any way with Symfony's user management. As @Mathieu_Dormeval pointed out you can get this from the security context.

(4) This retrieves whatever you have stored in the session under key `username` (in your case the name from (3)). Please be aware that you don't assign this value to a variable or output it, so the way it is written now it's kinda useless.

(5) This is probably the cause of your problems. Since we can't see the template it's hard to tell you what to do exactly. To just get a list of all the data in your session you could do the following in your index.html.twig:

```
{{ dump(test.all) }}
```

This will only work in development mode. `dump` is a helper method from Twig to output raw data, similar to PHP's `var_dump()` method. You assigned your session to the variable `test` in (5) by doing `['test' => $session]`. Writing `test.all` inside the dump is <s>equivalent</s> like the following PHP code:

```
var_dump($session->all());
```

Calling `all()` will return an array with all data stored in the session. For more practical ways to access the data in your session you can check what other methods Session provides: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html#session-attributes

Comment: Quick comment regarding (2) you can actually throw this away as the documentation says: "While it is recommended to explicitly start a session, a session will actually start on demand, that is, if any session request is made to read/write session data.". So by accessing the session in (3) it will use the already started session or start a new one.

Comment: Great answer can you please test documentation on this site : http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/symfony2/topic-requests/23997

Comment: Sorry, I don't really like stackoverflow documentation. I feel it diverts resources that should go into the official documentation instead. To be fair the official documentation on Session Management isn't too helpful and I will try to find some time to improve those instead.